# Bootstrap Dropdown Menus Acting Weird

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added Bootstrap Dropdowns to my website, and one of them doesn't work at all. The other three drop when clicked, but are pretty messed up. I couldn't get a Fiddle working, so here's a screenshot of one of the messed up ones and a little of the actual 'dropdown' part appearing way to the left, so you get the idea.
[image: The Screenshot]

**HTML:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Example
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header"><b>Example</b></li>
      <li><a href="example1.html">Example 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="example2.html">Example 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="example3.html">Example 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="example4.html">Example 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="example5.html">Example 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not adding CSS or JavaScript because it's just the Bootstrap. If anyone can spot my problem, it would be truly appreciated.

Comment: paste html , js , css here - only the dropdown - not whole page :)

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing the div wrapping the entire thing that should have the class of `.dropdown`

Here is a fiddle showing you it working [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/dvatd83a/)

It should look like the following:

```
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Example
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header"><b>Example</b></li>
                <li><a href="example1.html">Example 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="example2.html">Example 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="example3.html">Example 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="example4.html">Example 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="example5.html">Example 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That didn't work. If you have any other solutions, please do share them. I edited the question to show the added update, though. @DrinkinPeople

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me what version of bootstrap are you using?  I have added a fiddle demo to the answer to show you this working.  If it is not working for you then you have other issues than just your markup.

Comment: Well, it's now working, but it seems to have messed up all of my CSS. Oh well, I'll figure it out. Thanks for the help!